# New ActionBar for each Activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to make a different action bar for each activity in my project

for example I have activity one with actionBar of ( Setting Undo Redo ) 
and activity two with actionBar of ( Setting Exit )

Can someone suggest me a  way to do it 
I used the onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected for each activity but somehow it gives me error though

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.item1:
        onClick(imageButton);
        break;
    case R.id.item2:
        onClick(imageView1);
        break;
    case R.id.item3:
        onClick(imageView2);
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: "somehow it gives me error though" -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For achieving this you don't need to change the action bar... only you need to add options menu for each activity(i mean action button)..

please refer the following link

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html

Answer (score 0):

Create for every activity its menu.xml

For example:

**res/menu/activity_generic_menu.xml**

```
<!-- Battery info -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_battery"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_battery_icon_100"
    android:title="@string/action_battery"
    android:showAsAction="always" />


<!-- Disconnect / will display always -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_disconnect"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_cancel"
    android:title="@string/action_disconnect"
    android:showAsAction="always"/> </menu>
```

`

and on the other hand (**res/menu/another.xml**):

```
<!-- Info -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_about"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about"
    android:title="@string/action_about"
    android:showAsAction="always" /></menu>`
```

Then in every onCreateOptionsMenu you should inflate the menu you want to.

Comment: I should learn posting code here. I dont know why some lines arent shown as I expected. Hope anyways you understood this. :)